# Dynamic HTML selectors/options are not sent in form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have in my javascript code few selectors. One of them is the trigger for generating another selector:

```
<form id="reportform" name="reportform" action="">
    <table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="16">
        <thead>
            <th class="report" colspan="2">Select Scope</th>
            <th class="report" colspan="2">Select Date</th>
            <th class="report" colspan="2">Options</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            ...
                <td>
                    Period
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="period" name="period">
                        <option selected="selected" value="0">- Select -</option>
                        <option value="1">Day</option>
                        <option value="2">Month</option>
                        <option value="3">Year</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                ...
            </tr>
                ...
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td id="date-label2"></td>
                <td id="date2"></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td align="right">
                    <input id="go" class="go" type="submit" value="Report">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

When one of the options in period select is selected one function is executed:

```
$('#period').change(function() {
    switch($('#period').find(":selected").text()){
        case 'Day':
            clearDates();

            var label = document.getElementById("date-label");
            var txt = document.createTextNode("day");
            label.appendChild(txt);

            var day = document.getElementById("date");
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.className = "day-report";
            day.appendChild(input);
            break;
        case 'Month':
            ...
        case 'Year':
            ...
    }
});
```

Functions used here:

```
function clearDates(){
    var date = document.getElementById("date-label");
    while (date.hasChildNodes()) {
        date.removeChild(date.lastChild);
    }
    date = document.getElementById("date");
    while (date.hasChildNodes()) {
        date.removeChild(date.lastChild);
    }
    date = document.getElementById("date-label2");
    while (date.hasChildNodes()) {
        date.removeChild(date.lastChild);
    }
    date = document.getElementById("date2");
    while (date.hasChildNodes()) {
        date.removeChild(date.lastChild);
    }
}
```

The point is that when I click submit button I can't see the dynamic elements of the form serialized, and I suppose won't be send to the server.

```
$(function(){
    $("#reportform").submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
        return false;
    });
});
```

It is possible the form gets those dynamic fields?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is no "name" attribute for new created inputs.

Comment: Totally right. I solved it adding `input.name = "day";`. Thank you.